# Could not locate a bind configured on SQL expression or this Session

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use `Flask-SQLAlchemy` with multiple databases.
And although I specify `bind_key` for the `Table` and it works fine for `Model` and the new session, `db.session.execute` doesn't look up the bind key on the metadata associated with the table and throws an error:

```
$ python app.py 
model [] <-- works
new session [] <-- works
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\projects\flask-sqlalchemy\app.py", line 32, in <module>
    print('main session', db.session.execute(select(user)).all()) # <- UnboundExecutionError
  File "C:\Users\user\projects\flask-sqlalchemy\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\scoping.py", line 778, in execute
    return self._proxied.execute(
  File "C:\Users\user\projects\flask-sqlalchemy\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2306, in execute
    return self._execute_internal(
  File "C:\Users\user\projects\flask-sqlalchemy\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2179, in _execute_internal
    bind = self.get_bind(**bind_arguments)
  File "C:\Users\user\projects\flask-sqlalchemy\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\session.py", line 78, in get_bind
    return super().get_bind(mapper=mapper, clause=clause, bind=bind, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\projects\flask-sqlalchemy\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2786, in get_bind
    raise sa_exc.UnboundExecutionError(
sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: Could not locate a bind configured on SQL expression or this Session.
```

Here is a code example:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, select

app = Flask(__name__)
# app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///main.sqlite"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_BINDS"] = {"secondary": "sqlite:///secondary.sqlite"}

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = "secondary"
    user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_name = Column(String)

user = db.Table(
    "user_table",
    Column("user_id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("user_name", String),
    bind_key="secondary",
)

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all("secondary")

    print('model', db.session.execute(select(User)).all()) # <- works

    new_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=db.engines['secondary']))

    print('new session', new_session.execute(select(user)).all()) # <- works
    print('main session', db.session.execute(select(user)).all()) # <- UnboundExecutionError

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)
```

You can need just do `pip install -U Flask-SQLAlchemy` and run `python app.py` to test.

Tell me please am I doing something wrong or this is a bug?

I thought I shouldn't create sessions for each database manually.

[Documentation](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/binds/#:%7E:text=Models%20and%20tables%20with%20a%20bind%20key%20will%20be%20registered%20with%20the%20corresponding%20metadata%2C%20and%20the%20session%20will%20query%20them%20using%20the%20corresponding%20engine.)

Thanks.

Comment: You need to uncomment the  "SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI" line so that `db.session` gets configured.  Note that `user` is only created in the secondary db, so you can't query it with `db.session`.

Comment: @snakecharmerb
thanks for your response.
But when I uncomment ```SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI``` it tries to fetch from ```main.sqlite``` which is empty db and throws ```sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user_table``` which is right because ```user``` and ```user_table``` got created in ```secondary.sqlite```.

Comment: I can query with ```db.session``` when I use a ```Model``` with ```__bind_key__``` but I can't do the same when I use ```Table``` with ```bind_key```.